# overide the equal, toString, hashcode methods in Enum

Tags: java

I have one Enum like Below

```
public enum Game {
    CRICKET("cricket"),
    FOOTBALL("football"),
    VOLLEYBALL("volleyball")'

    private String val;

    private Game(String val) {
        this.val = val;
    }

    public String getValue() {
        return this.val;
    }
}
```

In here, Do I want to overide the equal(),hashCode(),toString() methods
based on this [What issues should be considered when overriding equals and hashCode in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27581/what-issues-should-be-considered-when-overriding-equals-and-hashcode-in-java/27609#27609)

Comment: Enum values being constants, why would you need `equals()` and `hashcode()` ?

Comment: The only problem, better use `private final String val;` (or `public`).

Comment: can I know? why did you suggest like above @JoopEggen

Comment: You are talking about correct semantics, possible problems. There are not any, but `Game.FOOTBAL.val` should simply be a constant, and then (if so desired) it could also be public, as nobody could do `Game.FOOTBALL = "socker";`. That would make the class 100% semantically correct. _Besides the `)'`  a typo for `);`_.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Question is meaningless, because you **cannot override `equal()` and `hashCode()` of an enum**.

That is because they are defined as `final` in the [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html) class, which implicitly is the base class of all `enum` types.

Comment: What about toString method?

Comment: @cvaram96 As the javadoc of Enum's [`toString()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--) says: *This method may be overridden, though it typically isn't necessary or desirable. An enum type should override this method when a more "programmer-friendly" string form exists.*

Answer (score 1):

No, `enum` is not a regular class (and as Andreas pointed out, they're `final` methods). For example, you don't need to use `equals()` to compare them, as there is a single instance of each `enum` value. This allows you to use `==` instead.

```
if(gameType == Game.CRICKET)
```

You can override `toString()`, as by default it prints the same as `name()`, which is just the name of the enum (e.g. `FOOTBALL`).

Comment: It's not just that you don't *need* to, it's really that you *can't*, since `equal()` and `hashCode()` are `final`.

Comment: @Andreas I didn't realize that. But that's even better!

Answer (score 0):

My first question is why you would need the enum to contain a String in the first place. The point of your enum already looks like it is to differentiate each type of game within a certain list of possible games. So the enum itself here functions as a constant value. For example you could do:

```
public void playGame( Game myGame ){
  switch(myGame){
    case FOOTBALL: 
      playFootball();
      break;
    case CRICKET:
      playCricket();
      break;
   // and so on but you get the point
}
```

Comment: As the [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Enum.html#toString--) says: *This method may be overridden, though it typically isn't necessary or desirable. An enum type should override this method when **a more "programmer-friendly" string** form exists.* --- So that's why.